# Maven generate-resources plugin

Tags: maven, resources, installation, pom.xml

I want to be able to add a generate-resources plugin such as it performs everytime I run an install (at the compile step) so I don't have to type this:

```
generate-sources install
```

How do I achieve that in my POM file?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't need the 'generate-resources' bit - this phase comes before the install phase in the lifecycle so just running

```
mvn install
```

should include the generate-resources phase. See http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html for details.

If you've a specific plugin you want to bind to the install phase, you specify that in the plugin section in your pom. That link shows you how to do that too.